# XML report is not generate while running multiple test case in Nunit

Tags: selenium, nunit

If  i run multiple test  case in visual  studio  it is  generate multiple log  report But  if i run all  test case using Nunit console(2.6.4) , it  generate only one test case report

Answer (score 0):

NUnit generates a TestResult.xml report if you run the console runner. That single report contains all the information about all the test cases you have executed.

When you run under Visual Studio using the NUnit adapter, you are not running the console runner (obviously) so no TestResult.xml report is generated.